# QGIS processing plugin doesn't show layers in dropdown menu (QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I'm trying to work up a minimal processing plugin. I'm using the basic plugin program generated by Plugin Builder. The only change I've made is to configure the input of the feature source to be a raster instead of a vector, as I'm trying to load a raster. However, when I launch the plugin, no layers appear. I even tried loading one by name as a default, but it isn't recognized. What am I doing wrong? There do not appear to be any error messages thrown on loading the plugin.

Here is the relevant code and an image showing my layers:

```
    def initAlgorithm(self, config):
        """
        Here we define the inputs and output of the algorithm, along
        with some other properties.
        """

        # We add the input vector features source. It can have any kind of
        # geometry.
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeRaster],
                defaultValue="UH_cube16_georeffed.tif"
            )
        )

        # We add a feature sink in which to store our processed features (this
        # usually takes the form of a newly created vector layer when the
        # algorithm is run in QGIS).
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT,
                self.tr('Output layer')
            )
        )
```

[image]

Comment: As the name suggests, `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource` is for vector data only. If you want to select a raster input, use [QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer.html)